# adjusting ties for kruskal.wallis

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis-test, ties

I would like to compare the means of three groups using the Kruskal Wallis test in R.

My data looks like this:

```
bosaov
    category count_genus proportion sampleID combination
1        Bos        1081     0.0892    C1_01          C1
9        Bos        7277     0.6637    C1_02          C1
17       Bos        4815     0.5736    C1_03          C1
.
.
.
161      Bos         914     0.0824    C2_01          C2
169      Bos        6935     0.6584    C2_02          C2
177      Bos        7703     0.6582    C2_03          C2
.
.
.
321      Bos           0     0.0000    C3_01          C3
329      Bos           0     0.0000    C3_02          C3
337      Bos           0     0.0000    C3_05          C3
.
.
.
```

I would like to compare the means of proportion (continous variable) for the three levels (C1, C2, C3) of combination.

As my data is not normally distributed I decided to use a Kruskal Wallis Test instead of one way ANOVA.

I use the R package PMCMR and the following lines of code:

```
kruskal.test(proportion ~ combination, data = Bosaov) 

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  proportion by combination
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 32.958, df = 2, p-value = 6.97e-08
```

And for the post-hoc Test:

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(x=Bosaov$proportion, g=Bosaov$combination, method="Tukey")

    Pairwise comparisons using Tukey and Kramer (Nemenyi) test  
                   with Tukey-Dist approximation for independent samples 

data:  Bosaov$proportion and Bosaov$combination 

   C1      C2     
C2 0.6     -      
C3 3.3e-07 3.8e-05

P value adjustment method: none 
Warning message:
In posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test.default(x = Bosaov$proportion, g = Bosaov$combination,  :
  Ties are present, p-values are not corrected.
```

I get the warning that ties are present, because in my data some values occur more than once (f.e. 0).

I tried to solve this problem by adjustig ties using

```
Bosaov$proportion <- rank(Bosaov$proportion, ties.method="random")
```

I don´t get the warning anymore but the problem with randomly adjusted ties is that I logically get not reproducible results. So I decided to use ties.method="average" instead:

```
Bosaov$proportion <- rank(Bosaov$proportion, ties.method="average")
```

But if I use ties.method="average" I still get the warning regarding persent ties.

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(x=Bosaov$proportion, g=Bosaov$combination, method="Tukey").

    Pairwise comparisons using Tukey and Kramer (Nemenyi) test  
                   with Tukey-Dist approximation for independent samples 

data:  Bosaov$proportion and Bosaov$combination 

   C1      C2     
C2 0.6     -      
C3 3.3e-07 3.8e-05

P value adjustment method: none 
Warning message:
In posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test.default(x = Bosaov$proportion, g = Bosaov$combination,  :
  Ties are present, p-values are not corrected.
```

This is how my adjusted ties look like

```
rank(Bosaov$proportion, ties.method="average")
 [1] 31.0 50.0 45.0 56.0 47.0 44.0 28.0 34.0 43.0 38.5 52.0 22.0 46.0 38.5 54.0 58.0 10.5 55.0 25.0 29.0 30.0 49.0 48.0 57.0 40.0
[26] 51.0 24.0 32.0 35.0 33.0 53.0 21.0 26.0 36.0 41.0 37.0 42.0 10.5 10.5 27.0 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5
[51] 10.5 10.5 10.5 23.0 10.5 10.5 10.5 10.5
```

I really don´t know what causes the warning message. I´m happy if anybody can help and hope I was clear about the problem. Sorry! That was my first post in this forum which is great I think!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you just wondering if anyone has seen this error message?

Comment: Kruskal-Wallis *doesn't* compare means (at least not without additional assumptions).

Comment: The K-W test is a special case of the proportional odds model.  The PO model can well handle arbitrarily heavy ties, in getting the likelihood ratio test for group differences.  You can also get simultaneous confidence limits for odds ratios that account for multiplicity.